# Why is the letter W called 'double U' rather than 'double V'?

Tags: history

Why is the letter W called double **'U'** rather than double **'V'**?

If we look well at this letter it looks as a combination of two (=double) V letters, so why is it referred as double **'U'** rather than double **'V'** - as it is in fact?

[image]

Comment: Research helps: https://www.dictionary.com/e/w/

Answer (score 5):

In old and Middle English (before 1500) u and v were just different ways of writing the same character.  At first a "double-u" sound was indicated by "uu". Norman scribes introduced something like *w*, but it could be written as UU or VV. It was only with the introduction of printing that the vv form came to be common.

So originally W really was UU,  but it was also VV because U and V were the same letter back then.

Comment: It is _double vé_ in French